# var dump is showing result but data is not getiing inserted in DB

Tags: php, database, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to post some value in DB but for some reason Data is not being inserted. The array that is returned from view is not empty. But the query is not executing.

Part of my View:

```
<?echo form_open_multipart('eva/evluation_questions_value_entry'); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($id) ?>">
<?php  foreach ($info as $row){ 
  echo "<div class='row'>";
  $i=$row->id;
  echo "<div class='firstc'>".$row->id ."</div>";

  echo "<div class='secondc'>".$row->name ."</div>";

  echo  '<input type="hidden" name="training_evaluation_entry_id'.$i.'" value='.$i.'>';
            //some codes
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">

  </form>
```

The controller:

```
    public function evluation_questions_value_entry() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->model('TrainingEvaluationModel');
    $trainingEvaluation = $this->TrainingEvaluationModel->evluation_questions_value_entry();
}
```

The Model:

```
$this->ip_address = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] . '||' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];        
$this->created_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this->created_by = 101;
$this->updated_on = null;
$this->updated_by = 0;


for ($i = 1; $i <= 13; $i++) {

    $this->training_evaluation_entry_id = $_POST['training_evaluation_entry_id'.$i];
    $this->value = $this->db->escape($_POST['group'.$i]);


    $query = "INSERT INTO training_evaluation_info(training_evaluation_entry_id,value,ip_address,created_by) 
    VALUES($this->training_evaluation_entry_id,$this->value,'$this->ip_address',$this->created_by)";
    if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
{
    return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
```

}

It does not give any error and data array is passed to the model properly but why it is not being inserted in DB??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoting aside which looks dangerous without escaping all fields (I recommend that you learn about parameterized queries), in this case you're simply setting `$query`;

```
$query = "INSERT INTO training_evaluation_info(training_evaluation_entry_id,value,ip_address,created_by) 
VALUES($this->training_evaluation_entry_id,$this->value,'$this->ip_address',$this->created_by)";
```

...but never actually executing it.

You'll want to add a;

```
$this->db->query($query);
```